# Common teacher physics misconceptions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, thermodynamics, education

What do you think are some misconceptions or mistakes university physics teachers make?
Do you know any topic which could be teach nowadays more easily than before?
Could you please give some examples, like this one
https://web.archive.org/web/20140427084226/http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/airplane/wrong1.html

Comment: There are always improvements to pedagogical techniques, new technology that enables new kinds of visualizations/demos, etc, but I don't think there is a systematic problem in university professors misunderstanding basic physics concepts...

Comment: your question as formulated sounds like it assumes as a starting point that physics teachers should have misconceptions. Maybe it's a claim you should justify?

Comment: One I have seen a few times (including a cosmologist) is to solve a problem with variable mass using F=vdm/dt+ma, which in general gives the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

I taught physics at a community college for 25 years and was on many hiring committees for adjunct and tenure-track positions. Because this was a community college, the average level of subject-matter knowledge was probably lower than among applicants at four-year schools, although the two bell curves would surely overlap. There would presumably be a similar contrast between people we interviewed and people who actually end up getting teaching jobs and having careers.

One of our most frequently asked interview questions was something like, "Please describe a common student misconception about Newton's third law, and  overcome teaching." We found that roughly half our applicants themselves had some of the classic student misconceptions.

It was also extremely common to find that (1) applicants had forgotten basic freshman-level physics that they hadn't used in their graduate programs (e.g., they couldn't use Maxwell's equations to find the field of a point charge), or (2) many had no significant knowledge of relativity and quantum mechanics (e.g., they couldn't explain why the helium-4 nucleus is especially stable).

Comment: Wow, this is the most rapid downvote I've ever seen on stackexchange. I clicked to submit my answer, and as soon as the page reloaded, I had a -1. Obviously nobody could possibly have read the answer that quickly. Physics.SE might want to think about what effect this kind of aggressively nasty behavior will have on its ability to attract future users who are knowledgeable.

Comment: Did you find applicants could quickly make up gaps in knowledge due to topics they forgot? Or did asking these basic questions act as a good predictor for teaching success? (I'm genuinely interested as a former postdoc that did a lot of research but little teaching)

Comment: @user306124 I didn't downvote but I suspect this happened because you answered an [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) question which is generally discouraged.

Comment: @Jonas ok, it was an answer to an off-topic question. However, it should not that difficult to see the "new contributor" flag. I think that it is more harmful to this site this downvote *without explanation* than the answer itself.

Comment: @giorgiop Seems like concern is why this answer has any up votes. The question is off-topic (and the OP has made a non-germane edit to get it in the reopen queue, which is how I came to see it twice). The answerer here, clearly DOES have SE experience from the comment left, despite having a new account, so should know better. Even if you ignore those issues, this doesn’t really answer the question. Now for 2-3 pity votes, the whole question won’t get handled by roomba and will be yet another poor Q&A cluttering the site. If this answer ok, then let’s stop wasting time with reviews and voting.

Comment: The question is about specific misconceptions among current teachers. Your answer is basically that most people who applied for jobs at your college weren't qualified. (Which is not a terribly uncommon finding in any hiring process, in my experience from multiple institutions and fields.) Assuming you didn't hire these people, they never became teachers - at least as far as you know - and even if they did, the question was for what misconceptions they had, not just that they had some.

Comment: @Brick, I did not upvoted or downvoted either the question or the answer, although I do not like both. My comment was just restrained to not explaining why when downvoting questions or answers from new contributors.